# Dropdown Menu Not Working because of quotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, list

I am working on trying to create a Drop Down menu that will allow users to choose a color for a sticker. Once the user chooses the desired color, a "buy" button will appear. I am using block codes for Wordpress and it seems that the blockcode for the button is creating an issue because of the quotation marks placement.

This is the Blockcode for the button:

```
[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]
```

Here is the code:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('ColorChoice').src = this.value">
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">White</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Black</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Gold</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Light Blue</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Teal</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Light Blue</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Blue</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Royal Blue</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Dark Red</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Red</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Orange</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Yellow</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Sunflower</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Lemon</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Light Green</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Green</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Pink</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Purple</option>
<option value="[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]">Silver</option>
```

It would be great if anyone has some input or a better way about doing this.

Comment: The code is showing up odd. Here is the end of the list code:

`</select><img id="ColorChoice">`

Answer (score 3):

You can either alternate between single and double quotes like so:

```
<option value="[wp_cart_button name='Army Baymax' price='2.50']">Silver</option>
```

Or escape the quotes:

```
<option value="[wp_cart_button name=\"Army Baymax\" price=\"2.50\"]">Silver</option>
```

Comment: After making that change, the code still shows up like this on the webpage: http://stickemstickers.net/Untitled.png

Comment: Which option did you try?

Comment: I made the changes this time using the /" and this is what it looks like:  http://stickemstickers.net/Untitled.png

Comment: Note that its a backslash, `\` not a forward slash

Comment: I checked and I am using a backslash.

Comment: how about alternating the quotes, so single on the outside and double within the shortcode like so: `<option value='[wp_cart_button name="Army Baymax" price="2.50"]'>Silver</option>`

Comment: that fixed the error but now the button shows up as a missing image link vs a button.

Comment: Hmm, without seeing your code I can't suggest much more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` or escape the `"` with `\`

```
<option value="[wp_cart_button name='Army Baymax' price='2.50']">White</option>
```

or

```
<option value="[wp_cart_button name=\"Army Baymax\" price=\"2.50\"]">White</option>
```

Comment: They guy above you said the same thing but I am having problems. Check out the comments.

Comment: make sure you are using `\"` not `/"`